# Excluding post type from WordPress link builder

Tags: custom-post-types, tinymce

I have created a custom post type with parameter 'public' set to true. This is because I have to have it accessible in plugins that help you to build queries for post display, such as the Views (part of Toolset) plugin.

On the other hand, when I create a new post or page and use the link builder I don't want entries of this post type to show up in the search box there. Is there any way to achieve this aim?

Comment: What is Link Builder?

Comment: I mean the button used to link stuff in TinyMCE.

Comment: you can use custom permalink plugin to change the url accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Versions <= 3.6.1

It looks like the function `wp_link_query()` is used to display the internal posts/pages when you press the *Or link to existing content* in the "link builder":

[image: Link builder]

`wp_link_query()` is defined in `/wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php`.

It is queried via the `wp_ajax_wp_link_ajax()`, defined in the file `/wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php`.

These functions don't have any explicit filters to change the query.

### Version 3.7 (?)

It looks like there are patches on the way introducing the filter `wp_link_query_args`

You can check it out here:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18042

The milestone is set as `3.7`, so this might be your lucky version ;-)

If that's the case, then you might probably fix this with:

### Example 1:

If you want to list the custom post types by hand:

```
/**
 * Filter the link query arguments to change the post types. 
 *
 * @param array $query An array of WP_Query arguments. 
 * @return array $query
 */
function my_custom_link_query( $query ){

    // change the post types by hand:
    $query['post_type'] = array( 'post', 'page' );  // Edit this to your needs

    return $query; 
}

add_filter( 'wp_link_query_args', 'my_custom_link_query' );
```

### Example 2:

If you only want to eliminate a single custom post type, but keep all the others, then you can try:

```
/**
 * Filter the link query arguments to change the post types. 
 *
 * @param array $query An array of WP_Query arguments. 
 * @return array $query
 */
function my_custom_link_query( $query ){

    // custom post type slug to be removed
    $cpt_to_remove = 'news';      // Edit this to your needs

    // find the corresponding array key
    $key = array_search( $cpt_to_remove, $query['post_type'] ); 

    // remove the array item
    if( $key )
        unset( $query['post_type'][$key] );

    return $query; 
}

add_filter( 'wp_link_query_args', 'my_custom_link_query' );
```

where I used the demo slug `'news'`.

Answer (score 2):

And here's how you would remove an array of post types from the edit link dialog:

```
function removeCustomPostTypesFromTinyMCELinkBuilder($query){
    $key = false;

    $cpt_to_remove = array(
        'cpt_one',
        'cpt_two',
        'cpt_three'
    );

    foreach ($cpt_to_remove as $custom_post_type) {
        $key = array_search($custom_post_type, $query['post_type']);
        if($key){
            unset($query['post_type'][$key]);
        } 
    }
    return $query; 
}
add_filter( 'wp_link_query_args', 'removeCustomPostTypesFromTinyMCELinkBuilder' );
```